# start program from bash script

Tags: bash, batch-file

I have a batch file for windows containing following:

```sh
start "" javaw -jar %~p0/app.jar
```

How to get the same command in a Bash script?

Comment: What does that command do?

Comment: it is analog for starting from a command line in windows: currentdir/javaw -jar app.jar;

In other words it executes java jar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
root=`dirname "$0"` # in case if I got %~p0
nohup javaw -jar "$root/app.jar" &
```

starts `javaw` in background.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [`open`](http://ss64.com/bash/open.html)

```sh
open javaw -jar ${0%/*}/app.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume its a Java Swing (GUI based) app. You should be able to execute it using this:

```
cd /path/to/app
java -jar myApp.jar
```

Simply paste this code as it is in your bash script. The "cd" should take care of path issues. Do note, that the terminal will be freed only when the Java app is exited.